# Ethereumjs-vm, run-transaction-complete example not printing storage

Tags: javascript, blockchain, ethereum, evm

Running the example mentioned in the title, there is no output after the "---Storage---" line. According to my understanding, there should be a null_radix stored at the created address. (running gives no exceptions) please correct me if I’m wrong!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[update]

At the following part of the example at the `runTx` function I've noticed that we refresh the `createdAddress` variable at every transaction even though it doesn't register a new contract. Therefore it leaves us with the loss of our contract's address and the `readStorage` function won't print any output.

I've fixed it by checking the `createdAddress` property for `null` before saving the value.

```
if (returns.createdAddress) {
  createdAddress = results.createdAddress
  console.log('address created: ' + createdAddress.toString('hex'))
}
```